Powershell to JSON multiple objects
I have multiple PS scripts from which I call log function and append them to the same logFile.log.
Part of script looks like this:
$logEntry = @(
        @{
            date       = $currentDate
            severity   = $Severity
            message    = $Message
            }
        )

    $jsonLogEntry = $logEntry | ConvertTo-Json

    Add-Content $newlogfile -Value $jsonLogEntry

After calling this function from multiple scripts and functions, log file looks like this:
{
    "date":  "2024-07-30 09:41:56.000",
    "severity":  "INFO",
    "message":  "This is a test log message"
}
{
    "date":  "2024-07-30 09:42:00.000",
    "severity":  "INFO",
    "message":  "This is a test log message"
}

Is there a way to add commas between { and } and add [ at the beginning and ] at the end if they don't exist?
I have tried with the separate function that looks like this:
 # Read all lines from the log file
    $logContent = Get-Content $LogFile

    # Remove any empty lines and join the content into a single string
    $logContent = ($logContent | Where-Object { $_ -ne "" }) -join "`n"

    # Add a comma between JSON objects if they don't already exist
    $logContent = $logContent -replace "}\s*{", "},`n{"

    # Add square brackets if they don't exist
    if (-not $logContent.StartsWith("["))
    {
        $logContent = "[`n$logContent"
    }

    if (-not $logContent.EndsWith("]"))
    {
        $logContent = "$logContent`n]"
    }

    # Write the formatted content back to the log file
    Set-Content $LogFile -Value $logContent -Force

This works if you call this function only once, but if I call it and after that if I call the first one, then it just adds new {object} after last square bracket and after that formatting doesn't work - sqare brackets stay at the middle and it is not in JSON format (it looks like this in the middle -
...}
]
{...

How to format it correctly? Is there a way to do it nicely?

The problem with a "running array" in JSON in a log file is that you need to go back and remove the previous trailing ] before appending, then adding ] back in, for every new log entry. Are you sure trying to structure the entire log file as raw JSON is a good idea?

I am not, I have no experience in PS so I am trying everything. What would be the better approach for this?

I'd personally prefer a single line per entry, eg "[$currentDate] $severity $message" |Add-Content -LiteralPath $newlogfile

@MathiasR.Jessen I know, but it needs to be in this format. It will be used in other application.

Does the other application need to read it in real time? You can always convert a complete log file to json after the fact (eg. when you're done writing to it). How many entries to you add to a single log file?

@MathiasR.Jessen it needs to, yes.

And how many entries to you usually add to a single log file? If it's a short run and only a few (thousand) entries then keep them all in memory and convert + write them to disk all at once at the end.

@MathiasR.Jessen you are correct, there won't be many entries in that file, less than 1000.

If you want to write one big JSON array to the log file, simply wait until you're done collecting all the log entries - ConvertTo-Json will see that you're converting multiple objects and construct the array for you as desired.

If you want to take the rewrite-after-the-fact approach, I suggest using a different intermediate format that's easier to append to - like a CSV file for example:
$logEntry = [pscustomobject]@{
    date       = $currentDate
    severity   = $Severity
    message    = $Message
}

$logEntry |Export-Csv $LogFile -Append -NoTypeInformation

Then after you're done, re-import the CSV-based log, convert to json, and write back to disk:
Import-Csv $LogFile |ConvertTo-Json |Set-Content $jsonExportFile

